# Vue.js how to check if inputs from child components are filled so parent component can able/disable a button

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Hi  I'm new to vuejs and I'm struggling figuring it out how to make this work.

I have 3 different child components in a parent component, each one of the child components have multiple text and radio inputs. What I want to acomplish is to be able to disable a button on the parent component if there are empty inputs or not selected radio buttons.

Can someone explain to me how could I approach this? Thank you!.

Comment: You can read more about [emitting events](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events) in Vue documentation. But if you want that other developers could help you more, you should post the codes of your components in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for how to emit data, opposite to passing data down through a prop.

Here is a small example for an input field.

Child1.vue

```
<template>
  <p>
    Write something:
    <input v-model="inputText" />
  </p>
  <p>{{ inputText }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputText: '',
    };
  },
  emits: ['emitInput'],
  watch: {
    inputText() {
      this.checkContent();
    },
  },
  methods: {
    checkContent() {
      this.$emit('emitInput', this.inputText === '');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

App.vue (parent):

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button :disabled="disabledButton">Parent Button</button>
    <Child1 @emitInput="parentMethod" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child1 from './Child1.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Child1,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      disabledButton: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    parentMethod(payload) {
      //Since you had a 2nd parameter on line 24 in Child1, you can access it.
      //We were checking if input is empty or not, returning a boolean.
      this.disabledButton = payload;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```